# how to add action with html button in laravel datatables 8.*

Tags: datatable, datatables, laravel-5.7

I have installed yajra laravel on my project, I try to add action column with html button with id, I am using yajra laravel, these are my yajra laravel version:

- "yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons": "3.*"
- "yajra/laravel-datatables-fractal": "1.*",
- "yajra/laravel-datatables-html": "3.*",
- "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "8.*"

How to add Action column with html button with id of data ?

here my datatables code to make datatables in laravel:

```
public function html()
    {
        $brands = Brands::select(array('brands.id','brands.name','brands.slug','brands.description','brands.logo','brands.published','brands.created_at','brands.updated_at'));
        return $this->builder()
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
//                    ->addAction(['width' => '80px'])
                    ->removeColumn('id')
                    ->addColumn($this->actionColumns())
                    ->parameters($this->getBuilderParameters());
    }
```

this is my complete code for make datatables in laravel:
https://pastebin.com/v1qYGNjb

here the result datatable:
[image]

I want to add button edit and delete in column Actions, how to do that with laravel datatables 8?
I am using laravel datatables as a service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function html()
    {
        $brands = Brands::select(array('brands.id','brands.name','brands.slug','brands.description','brands.logo','brands.published','brands.created_at','brands.updated_at'));
        return $this->builder()
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
//                    ->addAction(['width' => '80px'])
                    ->removeColumn('id')
                    ->addColumn('action',function ($data){
                return $this->getActionColumn($data);
            })
                    ->parameters($this->getBuilderParameters());
    }

/**
     * @param $data
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getActionColumn($data): string
    {
        $showUrl = route('admin.brands.show', $data->id);
        $editUrl = route('admin.brands.edit', $data->id);
        return "<a class='waves-effect btn btn-success' data-value='$data->id' href='$showUrl'><i class='material-icons'>visibility</i>Details</a> 
                        <a class='waves-effect btn btn-primary' data-value='$data->id' href='$editUrl'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i>Update</a>
                        <button class='waves-effect btn deepPink-bgcolor delete' data-value='$data->id' ><i class='material-icons'>delete</i>Delete</button>";
    }
```

1. Change your addColumn() method and follow this code.

Answer (score 2):

```
//UsersDataTable.php file


class UsersDataTable  extends DataTable{
    public function dataTable( $query ){
        return datatables()
            ->eloquent( $query )
            ->addColumn( 'action', function( $data ){ // $data is data od current row in table 
                return view( 'admin.users.action', [ 'data' => $data ] ); // return view with objects (row) data parameters
                //return '<a href="#">'.$data->id.'</a>'; // or simply return html here
            } );
    }

    // some of class code here

    protected function getColumns(){
        return [
            Column::make( 'id' ),
            Column::make( 'name' )->title( 'Nazwa' ),
            Column::make( 'email' ),
            Column::make( 'created_at' ),
            Column::make( 'updated_at' ),
            
            Column::computed( 'action' )
                  ->exportable( FALSE )
                  ->printable( FALSE )
                  ->width( 60 )
                  ->addClass( 'text-center' ),
        ];
    }
    
}


//UsersController.php file

use App\DataTables\UsersDataTable;
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index(UsersDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        return $dataTable->render('admin.users.index');
    }
}
```